# Can I mix SAS and SATA HDDs together using LVM?

Tags: lvm

I was playing with my server with a 300G SAS HDD. However, recently I am considering making it into a production server which demands elastic storage. So I meet the question that whether it is okay to mix SAS and SATA HDDs in LVM because I can not afford SAS drives.
Any ideas about this?

Comment: LVM doesn't care, any block device will do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LVM itself doesn't care what the underlying storage is: SATA, SCSI; HDD, SSD; local, networked; physical, virtual; etc.

Different types of disks have different performance characteristics, so you may want to put the different types of disks in different groups anyway. But this is not required. You may also want to span groups over different storage types and put ordinary logical volumes and snapshot LVs on different PVs. Again, it depends on your needs.